# "Maths is worth learning for everyone" - Is this correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> Maths is worth learning for everyone

I'm a native speaker but I cannot for the life of me tell if this sentence is correct... I'm not sure if the problem is the preposition or *worth* vs *worthwhile*, or if there's no problem at all and I'm just being silly. It seemed correct at first but then it got got weirder the more I thought about it...

This version sounds more natural to me:

> It is worthwhile for everyone to learn maths

Comment: You sure it's not about math vs maths - that's the first thing that struck me.

Comment: Note that in US English it's always **math**, never **maths**.

Comment: And in British it is always maths, but treated as singular. That's not the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct but it does not sound natural because we expect **learning** to be followed by the subject being learned:

> I am learning french.

We can fix this easily by moving **learning** to the beginning of the sentence: we also have to switch to worthwhile because worth must be followed by a noun phrase.

> Learning maths is worthwhile for everyone.

In your second sentence, **for everyone to learn maths** sounds like nobody will benefit unless everybody does it. You can fix this by replacing everyone by anyone.

> It is worthwhile for anyone to learn maths.

You could also split worthwhile, and use **would** to make it more of a polite suggestion:

> It would be worth anyone's while to learn maths.